# Relationship between the application service layer and the aggregate root

Tags: design-patterns, .net, domain-driven-design

I understand the relationship between an aggregate root and a repository i.e. there should be one repository per aggregate root.

What is the relationship between the application service layer and the aggregate root/repository.  I assume there should be one application service per aggregate root?

Should the application service use the aggregate root entity only from the business layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such relation from `Application layer` to `Domain layer`. For example you could have an `Application service` that uses two or more repositories for one use case (but each repository with its own transaction).

From my experience, in general, I have an `Application service` for each use case.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the reference to Use Cases.  I was reading earlier that the one repository per agregate root rule only applies to SELECTS.  Apparently an aggregate can use more than one repository for UPDATES.

Comment: I think there must be a relation between Application Layer and Domain Layer. Application services can use domain services. http://www.joaopauloseixas.com/howtodoit.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Domain-Driven-Design-Overview-of-a-Layered-Architecture.png

Comment: @MohamedBouallegue Yes, but not "relation" in this context as in 1-to-1

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu now it make sense